# How does one use memit magic?

Tags: python, memory, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run the following code in a jupyter notebook:

```
%%memit
list1 = [i*i for i in range(100_000)]
lista2 = list1
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
UsageError: Cell magic `%%memit` not found.
```

If instead of `memit`, I use `timeit`, everything works.

Comment: Have you read the docs https://jupyter-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/performance/ipython-profiler.html?

Answer (score 0):

Yes because, `time*` is available by default, `memit` instead requires to be manually installed.

[Here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.07-timing-and-profiling.html) you  can find all needed info.

### Briefly

It must be installed and enabled:

```
$ pip install memory_profiler

%load_ext memory_profiler
```

That's it